# OData Upgrade Breaks any-to-many Expansion?

Tags: entity-framework, odata

So in production I've got an old Microsoft-based OData service that's working off of an EF6 DbContext with one of these `*:*` relationships added to its OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ChipsetComponent>().
                HasMany(c => c.Processors).WithMany(p => p.ChipsetComponents).Map(map =>
                {
                    map.ToTable("api_1_0_ProcessorChipsetCompatibility");
                    map.MapRightKey("ProcessorId");
                    map.MapLeftKey("ChipsetProductId");
                });
```

And that allowed (past tense, when using EF 5 + OData 3, I think) ChipsetComponents()?$expand=Processors to work just fine. But after upgrading to OData 5.6.4, trying to use the $expand specifically breaks claiming:

```
"innererror":{
"message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
"type":"System.NullReferenceException",
"stacktrace":"   at System.Data.Services.WebUtil.GetRequestEnumerator(IEnumerable enumerable)\r\n   at System.Data.Services.QueryResultInfo.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Data.Services.Serializers.EntitySerializer.WriteNavigationProperties(IExpandedResult expanded, EntityToSerialize entityToSerialize, Boolean resourceInstanceInFeed, IEnumerable`1 projectionNodesForCurrentResourceType) ...
```

Making a call against ChipsetComponents()/Processors still works just fine after the version updates (but doesn't get me ChipsetComponents' data, of course), and I've re-confirmed the data integrity, so the relationship isn't completely missing, it's just apparently malformed in how the current OData is relating to the current DbContext.

Has anybody seen & overcome something similar?

**Update:**

This is actually impacting all of my x-to-many relationships defined with ICollection properties like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Processor> Processors { get; set; }
```

Previously they were not initialized in class constructors and this was Just Fine because if they weren't expanded (which populated them) then they also weren't looked at. I've tested initializing them in class constructors in case this was a change and now they $expand to [] instead of having data in them, which is not an error but is still totally wrong.

It looks like $expand is simply failing to fetch the data expected of it, but everything else works the same and expects $expand to work the same, too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I needed to follow this process here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2013/10/02/using-wcf-data-services-5-6-0-with-entity-framework-6.aspx (Install a new package & convert from `DataService<T>` to `EntityFrameworkDataService<T>` as the service's base class.)

The "current" version of the package in question is a **10-month-old Beta 2**, which is a bit hard on my confidence for production but hasn't given me functional grief yet:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider/1.0.0-beta2